# How to format a printed line that is looped in Java

Tags: java, loops, printf

I'm pretty new to Java programming and couldn't find an answer to my problem anywhere. Basically, I have successfully created a program that builds a chart of Celsius to Fahrenheit conversions and Fahrenheit to Celsius conversions, however my looped print statements are not lined up correctly after the number 9 similar this:

9.0    48.2    40.0     4.44  
10.0     50.0    41.0    5.0

I was required to use two separate methods to calculate the conversions and then call them within the main method. Here is the main method with the println statement that I am reffering to:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
   double celsius = 1;
   double fahrenheit = 32;

   while(celsius <= 50 && fahrenheit <= 120){

     double toFarhenheit = celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius);
     double toCelsius = fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit); 

     DecimalFormat fardec = new DecimalFormat("#.##");  
     toFarhenheit = Double.valueOf(fardec.format(toFarhenheit));

     DecimalFormat celsdec = new DecimalFormat("#.##");  
     toCelsius = Double.valueOf(celsdec.format(toCelsius));

     System.out.println(celsius + "   " + toFarhenheit + "  " + fahrenheit + 
           "  " +toCelsius);

     celsius++;
     fahrenheit++;            
   }    
}
```

To make a long story short, is there anyway to use a printf with this kind of long print statement so that the numbers will line up with one another?

In the past I have used printf %3d and %5d and the like to line integers up, however, I couldn't get this to work at all with this particular print statement.

Any ideas and/or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Bad code formatting corrected. Please put some effort into making your code readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **\t** to format them as this spaces them out evenly.

```
System.out.println(celsius + "\t" + toFarhenheit + "\t" + fahrenheit + 
       "\t" +toCelsius);
```

Comment: This could lead to unreliable results.

Comment: This solution did work for me, thanks Troubleshoot. Hovercraft, how could this lead to unreliable results?

Comment: It could lead to unreliable results if a string of characters is longer than the tab, though the code you provided wouldn't allow that.

Answer (score 4):

Use `System.out.printf(...)` and a format String to output your data in regular columns. Avoid using `\t` as it is unreliable.  For example please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9997531/522444).

Eventually your code would look like:

```
System.out.printf(formatString, celsius, toFarhenheit, fahrenheit, toCelsius);
```

Where the formatString is a String that uses printf format specifiers and width constants that would allow for pretty output. I'll let you experiment with format Strings. It would also end with "%n" so that it becomes in effect a println with formatting.

Comment: Thanks HFOE, I've been messing around with the format Strings. I still am unable to get all four lines to work, only the first celsius actually prints, and I did add the "%n" to the end of my format string.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Hovercraft Full Of Eels said, using System.out.printf without `"\t"` is a better solution. 
For example, you should be able to do something like this:

```
String myformat = "%0$10s";
```

Explanation of the format:

1. `%0s` identifies your output as a string
2. `$10` tells it to ensure that a minimum of 10 characters are written to the output. Hence, you'll have a fixed width.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax for some more details

[haven't used java in a while so someone do correct me if I'm off]

Answer (score 0):

Using "\t" or using printf is probably not going to help you out as what ever space is being added takes into consideration the 2 string literals. For Eg. 9.0 is 3 chars long and 10.0 is 4 chars long.. so in this case spaces applied are correct but your string literals itself are of different length.

Try changing the code like below, use one more hash.

```
DecimalFormat fardec = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
```